# One word for "put something to a lower form/level/grade"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "put something to a lower form/level/grade (than it should be)"?

All I can think of are

> - reduce
> - cast something low

But I would like to assert the sense that the object deserves more recognition or value.

For example, to a friend who describes humans as mere animals whose behavior is dictated and predicted by biological and evolutionary principles,

> You reduce the human race to a mere conglomerate of biological and evolutionary rules.

in the sense that the statement puts something in a lower position, not giving its full value.

Comment: You really need to indicate whether you are looking for an act of assessment  ('undervalue') (which only has secondary effects on the situation) or a speech act (downgrade / demote) which is an executive act.

Comment: In the context provided, *reduce* is exactly the correct word.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could consider using the verb [***degrade***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/degrade) which means:

> Lower the character or quality of

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

> Slavery was a known practice which was used in the world to ***degrade
>   human beings*** to the level of commodity and animals.

[The Historian 2007]

Answer (score 28):

"Demote" might be appropriate.

**Move (someone) to a lower position or rank, usually as a punishment:
 ‘the head of the army was demoted to deputy defence secretary’.**

(Oxford On-Line Dictionary)
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demote

Comment: @ErikE What if the source is a dictionary, which typically doesn't say who wrote which definitions?

Comment: @ErikE  It didn't come from any particular source, but just from my knowledge as a mature native speaker of BrE. Anyone (including the OP) is free to look it up themselves in any dictionary to verify it's meaning. Please don't nit-pick.

Comment: @ ErikEHave edited my post with a reference and link to a reliable source.

Comment: @BillJ Looks far better than before. +1) :-)

Comment: Comments edited and voted.

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest the word *relegate*.

> **relegate**
>
> To consign to an inferior or obscure place, rank, category, or condition: an artist's work that is now relegated to storerooms; a group that has been relegated to the status of second-class citizens.
>
> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relegate
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relegated

Comment: I understand this is the specific term in European soccer leagues when being demoted.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_and_relegation

Answer (score 10):

Consider, ***debase***.

> 1. to reduce in quality or value.
> 2. to lower in rank or dignity.
>
> [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/debase)

Answer (score 9):

denigrate

criticize unfairly; disparage.
"there is a tendency to denigrate the poor"

Comment: This was my first thought.

Comment: Hi kyle, welcome to EL&U. If your words are a quote, the [site rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) require a link to the source (if found online) and the original author's name in plain text (or link text, not hidden behind the link). Using an official definition of the word would be an improvement to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic term is *undervalue*.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/undervalue):

> undervalue V [WITH OBJECT] (often as adjective undervalued)
>
> 1 Rate (something) insufficiently highly; fail to appreciate:
>   *the skills of the housewife remain undervalued in society*

Comment: I feel that this and "denigrate" are the only current answers whose connotations meet the OPs condition of the "lowering" being an undeserved, inappropriate or unfair act.

Answer (score 6):

Consider **belittle** and **depreciate**

> 1. lower the value of something
> 2. lose in value

Comment: Hi @Huang, welcome to ELU. Your answer would be improved if you added a citation and link for where you got your definition from.

Comment: Thank you for your mention! I'll improve my answers later on:)

Answer (score 3):

Consider **to lower**:

> to lower: To reduce in **value**, degree, or quality.

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lower))

> **Humans are lowered to the level of animals**, and as you eat your holiday turkey there is no difference in eating your own children.

([adsoftheworld.com](http://adsoftheworld.com/media/print/wwf_baby))

Another alternative is **to bring down**:

> bring down: to reduce the rate, **level**, or amount of something

(Macmillan Dictionary)

> declaring humans and animals equal – the goal is not to elevate animals but to **bring humans down to the level of animals**

([wattsupwiththat.com](http://wattsupwiththat.com/2013/10/11/political-scientists-gerald-north-and-andrew-dressler-double-down-on-climate-alarmism/))

Answer (score 3):

I like "diminish".

> **diminish**
>
> 1. to make or cause to seem smaller, less, less important, etc.; lessen; reduce.
> 2. to detract from the authority, honor, stature, or reputation of; disparage.
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diminish

Comment: It is not wrong to include supporting evidence *in your answer* rather than just a link. Due to link rot and just because we want questions and answers to stand on their own, it's actually preferred. And as you have done it is important to credit your sources.

Answer (score 2):

The word "devolve" comes to mind.  As in, "Political discussion has devolved on both ends of the political spectrum in recent years."  I'm quoting myself FWIW.
"The lamentable change is from the best. The worst returns to laughter." - Shakespeare - King Lear

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [degrade](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/degrade?s=t)... Or [downgrade](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/downgrade?s=t).

Depending on your context one of these option may be better than the other. Both carry the connotation of being relegated to a lower level or grade, but both are not equal in tone.

Degrade holds a negative connotation and implies that the action had a malicious intent. Downgrade has a more utilitarian tone, and implies less emotional motivation for the action.

Your two suggestion feel a little more emotionally charged to me, so maybe degrade would be the better option of the two.

Comment: Added as a comment - as I think it suits, but please add a reference to your answer :
       Downgrade
verb
ˈdaʊnɡreɪd,daʊnˈɡreɪd/
1.
reduce to a lower grade, rank, or level of importance.

Comment: Please explain why these words are good choices.

Answer (score 1):

Although not as unambiguous as Edwin Ashworth’s answer (undervalue), ODO’s first definition of [devalue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/devalue) would work in your example

("verb [with object] 1Reduce or underestimate the worth or importance of: I resent the way people seem to devalue my achievement"):

> You **devalue** [the] human race to a mere conglomerate of biological and
>   evolutionary rules.

Answer (score 1):

"Dumb down."

> `Andy:`  The kids had a hard time understanding the old textbooks.
>   `Beth:`  What was the books' reading level?
>   `Andy:`  They scored a 12 on the Flesch-Kincaid index.
>   `Beth:`  No wonder we got the **dumbed-down** books.
>   `Andy:` Yeah, the new ones only scored a 5 on the Flesch-Kincaid index.
>   `Beth:`  Even our kids should be able to understand them.  Let's hope they don't get bored.

Comment: "Dumb-down" and "water-down" both do have the meaning of "reduce in complexity" but do not fit the OP's context.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a simple word such as 'revert' would suffice?

Comment: Maybe, but please explain why you think so.